# How to move accounts and contacts from one salesforce org to another org

Tags: data-import-wizard

I want to move accounts and contacts from one salesforce org to another.
I know i can use the import wizard. The question i have is about setting up the csv file.

Do i have a single csv for both accounts and contacts or have individual csv for accounts and contacts?

EDIT:

PS: We have a group edition so we need to use only the import wizard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have them in 1 import file. Use the "Customize Mapping" button, you'll see details (first 2 screens will talk about contact, next 2 about Account). You can even map 1 column to multiple fields - might be useful for address data for example.

Check out the training video - Help & Training in upper right corner, then search for "Advanced Importing" (there are also versions for System Administrators but not too different). In case of trouble - hopefully this direct link will work: https://salesforce.adobeconnect.com/_a13852757/importing. Video is very old (pre-Chatter page layouts) but does it's job well :)

Comment: Thanks that helped.. there was no where they were mentioning how to create the csv file, but pointers from the video helped me find a link where they asked to create a report with the contact and account records and then export to csv to get the merged csv